# Saving a chart as an image in MPAndroidChart

Tags: android, mpandroidchart, save-image

I am using the MPAndroidChart to render various charts. I wanted to add the functionality of saving the charts as images to the gallery. I added an icon to the action bar to use this functionality, but the image does not save to the gallery.

The code is given below :

```
<item android:id="@+id/save"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_accept"
    android:title="@string/save"
    app:showAsAction="always"/>
```

---

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.save :
            mlineChart.saveToGallery("Chart",50);
            return true;
        case R.id.action_settings :
            return true;
        default: return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: do you have write external storage permission in your manifest
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

Comment: Adding the permission did it. :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From  *[How to programatically take a screenshot on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2661536/how-to-programatically-take-a-screenshot-on-android)*

```
// image naming and path  to include sd card  appending name you choose for file
String mPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/" + ACCUWX.IMAGE_APPEND;   
// create bitmap screen capture
Bitmap bitmap;
View v1 = mWebview.getRootView(); // take the view from your webview
v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(v1.getDrawingCache());
v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);

OutputStream fout = null;
imageFile = new File(mPath);

try {
  fout = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
  bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, fout);
  fout.flush();
  fout.close();

} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

**Update**

Thanks tamim for pointing this deprecation out. Here is the updated solution

public void setDrawingCacheEnabled (boolean enabled)

> This method was deprecated in API level 28. The view drawing cache was
>   largely made obsolete with the introduction of hardware-accelerated
>   rendering in API 11. With hardware-acceleration, intermediate cache
>   layers are largely unnecessary and can easily result in a net loss in
>   performance due to the cost of creating and updating the layer. In the
>   rare cases where caching layers are useful, such as for alpha
>   animations, setLayerType(int, android.graphics.Paint) handles this
>   with hardware rendering. For software-rendered snapshots of a small
>   part of the View hierarchy or individual Views it is recommended to
>   create a Canvas from either a Bitmap or Picture and call
>   draw(android.graphics.Canvas) on the View. However these
>   software-rendered usages are discouraged and have compatibility issues
>   with hardware-only rendering features such as Config.HARDWARE bitmaps,
>   real-time shadows, and outline clipping. For screenshots of the UI for
>   feedback reports or unit testing the PixelCopy API is recommended.

So as per the recommendations use [PixelCopy](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/PixelCopy.html) for fetching  screenshots / snapshot of the UI.It's available in API level 24 and above

```
PixelCopy.request(surfaceViewObject,BitmapDest,listener,new Handler());
```

where,

surfaceViewObject is the object of surface view

BitmapDest is the bitmap object where the image will be saved and it cant be null

listener is OnPixelCopyFinishedListener

for more info refer [Pixel Copy Android Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/PixelCopy)

Comment: setdrawingcacheenabled is now deprecated on api 28, is there an other approach we can use safely?

Comment: Thanks for the solution.
check my answer if you want to achieve this without the usage of PixelCopy, because in some cases you need the bitmap directly and not through a callback.

Answer (score 2):

Using Kotlin extentions, I was able to achieve it this way:

```
//create a bitmap using view height and width to draw to it
fun View.getBitmap(): Bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(measuredWidth, measuredHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888).also {
    //create a canvas for this bitmap (it)
    Canvas(it).apply {
        //if the view has a background, draw it to the canvas, else draw a white screen 
        //because canvas default background is black
        background?.draw(this) ?: drawColor(Color.WHITE)
        //draw the view to the canvas
        draw(this)
    }
}
```

The reason I used `measuredWidth` and Height is because when you have a scrollable view or a `ViewGroup` the screenshot is clipped.